# Obfuscate iOS project using iOS ClassGuard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, obfuscation, xcode7

How to obfuscate iOS project using iOS ClassGuard project:
https://github.com/Polidea/ios-class-guard

I am using this project to obfuscate my iOS project. Unfortunately, it is not working, throwing error.

I followed the steps provided to How to use it. But, when I am doing

```
bash obfuscate_project
```

The build was successful but it crashed after that. Here is the report:

> ios-class-guard[57105:1897397] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>
> exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'working directory
> doesn't exist.'
>
> *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff856ad03c __exceptionPreprocess + 172  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
> 0x00007fff88bf876e objc_exception_throw + 43  2   CoreFoundation
>
> 0x00007fff856aceed +[NSException raise:format:] + 205     3   Foundation
>
> 0x00007fff86d682a6 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:] + 582  4
>
> ios-class-guard                     0x000000010f1db7d6
>
> -[CDSystemProtocolsProcessor systemProtocolsSymbolsToExclude] + 534   5   ios-class-guard                     0x000000010f1977e2 main + 6110  6
>
> libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8b4275c9 start + 1 )
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>
> NSException obfuscate_project: line 28: 57105 Abort trap: 6
>
> "$@"

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue. Steps that I took to fix this are:

1. Add "symbols.h" file in the project.
2. Import "symbols.h" file in your .pch file.
3. Add "symbols.h" file only for release mode, importing that file like this:

   ## ifndef DEBUG

   ```
   #import "symbols.h"
   ```

   ## endif
4. Now compile the project for anything - "Debug" or "Release" mode. Everything work fine without errors.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
Fixed this issue following these steps:

What to change while obfuscation:

1. cd project folder path

2. Download iOS ClassGuard project.
curl -o obfuscate_project https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Polidea/ios-class-guard/master/contrib/obfuscate_project && chmod +x obfuscate_project

3. change mode:
chmod +x obfuscate_project

4. Open obfuscate_project in text editor
change following things:

From...

PROJECT=YourProject.xcodeproj
SCHEME=YourScheme
CONFIGURATION=Release
SDK=7.1


From...
"--sdk-root /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator$SDK.sdk"

To...

"--sdk-root /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk"


5. bash obfuscate_project
This will start building the project and after that it will obfuscate.
Two files will be created: 1. symbols.h and 2. symbols.json
pch file will be modified

But after obfuscating, the project is not compiling. 
It is throwing error: 

> Use of undeclared identifier
```

Comment: But this has created another issue. After obfuscating the project, it is not compiling. I am using xcode 7.0. It is throwing error - "No visible @interface for All the classes".

Comment: I got tons of " Unexpected '@' in program" when I build my project....after obfuscating. The Polidea doesn't maintain this ios-class-guard over 5 months!!!

Comment: Have you figure out this problem? I have the same problem.

Comment: I am trying hard to get rid of it but, no luck as of now. Please let me know, if you come to know any solution for it.

Comment: Based on Git, I can see ios-class-guard only modified my Prefix.pch and symbols.h and storyboard. My obfuscate_project bash was working great under the XCode 6. But, now, I have to solve bugs in the bash one by one. Currently, I am stock on ignore list.   The terminal outputs shown one of my ignore parameter (-i "DTAlert*") was not working, the class was obfuscated. I got "Unexpected '@' in program" error messages in XCode.

Comment: Same is happening with me also. bash is working fine fine. The code is obfuscated successfully but i see errors everywhere in my project saying the same thing as you mentioned.

Comment: There is new version (0.8) of `iOS Class Guard` with Xcode7 support. Should works fine now.

Comment: They need to add reserved keywords like 'end' 'interface' 'implementation' 'class' 'protocol'. Maybe it's already done, but I've spent ~4 hours trying to obfuscate my application and it was failing always. By using this technique I've succeeded, but got these tons of errors. This is because it obfuscated special keywords.

Comment: You might want to look at [PPiOS-Rename](https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename), which is a fork of ios-class-guard that fixes a number of these issues, and works on Xcode 7.3.